# Screen sharing capabilities

Tags: screensharing

I am trying to develop a screen sharing application. I would like to know how the screen sharing works on the desktop by sending and receiving network packets. Can i get any architecture or help on how it works in depth?
I searched a lot in google search, but couldn't find enough information.
If anyone who already have done research on this topic, and could share information or links or tutorials or design, that would help a lot.

Getsy

Comment: Which platforms do you wish to support?

Comment: And what is the definition of "screen sharing"? Is it remote desktop or team view?

Answer (score 5):

Probably you may not necessarily need to re-invent the wheel.

Best approach in my view is to take some of the libraries available around the internet. Specially interesting is if you take some open source project, which will allow you easily to link to your software, using it such as an API/Lib. Depending on the project source code you decide to use, you can even branch it contributing with a patch.

Here is some good code you can possibly re-use:

*** FreeRDP / FreeRDP
https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP

*** multiremotedesktopclient
http://code.google.com/p/multiremotedesktopclient

*** Multi RDP Client .NET
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33979/Multi-RDP-Client-NET

*** properJavaRDP
http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net

If you still need some further suggestions, just let me know.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. I want to do screen sharing through my program, from mac to mac environment.

Comment: Also, need an explanation about how screensharing works in general? Is it through screenshot sharing or packets screen or what else way? If its packet sharing, how does it work? How the screen can be converted as packets?

Comment: also worth to take a look inside google remote desktop
really nice code, a lot of info can be learned from it about basics of RDP

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

What system are you using? I'd say that X events forwarding may be simplest way for you, if ypu're using unix. If not, AFAIR there are ports of X Windows System with Cygwin or smth.

Comment: I don't really understand..I am newbie for screen sharing stuff..please give me how screensharing works, how can i achieve that etc. details first...thanks.